# How to use dxRibbon component? Help me

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have used dxRibbon component.
But while compiling it raises the error

> file not found dxribboncustomizationform.dcu

[image]

What should I do???

Comment: Did you add the directory of the units to the library path?

Comment: Pretty sure the DX installer did not add those paths.
The default DCU path for XE7-Win32 is:
..\DevExpress VCL\Library\RS21

Comment: @FredS Considering those paths in the image are black and not gray, tells me they are all valid paths.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge - True but source is a level below that so AFAIK those paths point to two sub-folders, packages and source.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to a Cmd prompt at your top level DexExpress folder.
- Do a

```
Dir dxribboncustomizationform.dcu /S
```

- Depending on your set-up you may find the .Dcu file in more than one folder
  below

  DevExpress VCL /Library
- Add whichever folder contains the most recent version of the .Dcu file to your project's Library path, preferably ahead of the existing Devex ones (some folders may be labelled for 64-bit & you should ignore those if your project is 32-bit, of course).

If the `Dir` step doesn't find the .Dcu, your best bet is to uninstall the Devex libraries and re-install them from scratch.